# how to add submit function to js Onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to trigger a url when click on a button, when click on the delete button it triggers the JS Alert but it is not passing the link, it removes the button instead. how can make it process the link once i confirm the alert?

js code

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#demo').confirmOn('click', function() {
$(this).remove();
});
});
</script>
```

html

```
<a href="index.php?page=test:delete&item_id={item_id}" id="demo">
<input type="button" class="log_button" value="Delete"/>
```

ConfirmOn code..

```
(function($) {
var confirmOn = $.confirmOn = {};

confirmOn.providedOptions = {};

confirmOn.defaultSettings = {
    questionText: 'Are you sure?',
    classPrepend: 'confirmon',
    textYes: 'Yes',
    textNo: 'No'
};

confirmOn.overrideDefaultSettings = function(settings) {
    confirmOn.defaultSettings = $.extend({}, confirmOn.defaultSettings, settings);
};

confirmOn.setOptions = function($element, options) {
    options = $.extend({}, confirmOn.defaultSettings, options);
    $element.data('confirmon', {
        options: options
    });
};

confirmOn.createOverlay = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    return $('<div/>').addClass(classPrepend + '-overlay').hide().appendTo('body');
};

confirmOn.showOverlay = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    $('.' + classPrepend + '-overlay').fadeIn();
};

confirmOn.deleteOverlay = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    $('.' + classPrepend + '-overlay').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
};

confirmOn.createBox = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    var questionText = $element.data('confirmon').options.questionText;
    var textYes = $element.data('confirmon').options.textYes;
    var textNo = $element.data('confirmon').options.textNo;

    var $box = $('<div/>').addClass(classPrepend + '-box').hide().appendTo('body');
    $('<p class="' + classPrepend + '-content"/>')
        .html(questionText)
        .appendTo($box);
    $('<button class="' + classPrepend + '-button ' + classPrepend + '-button--yes"/>')
        .html(textYes)
        .appendTo($box);
    $('<button class="' + classPrepend + '-button ' + classPrepend + '-button--no"/>')
        .html(textNo)
        .appendTo($box);

    $('.' + classPrepend + '-button').on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.which === 9) { //Tab key
          e.preventDefault(); 
          $('.' + classPrepend + '-button').not(this).focus();
        } 
    });

};

confirmOn.showBoxAndFocusNo = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    $('.' + classPrepend + '-box').fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).children('button').eq(1).focus();
    });
};

confirmOn.deleteBox = function($element) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    $('.' + classPrepend + '-box').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
};

$.confirmOn.handleEscKey = function($element) {
    $(document).on('keydown.confirmon.close', function(e){
        if (e.which === 27) { //Esc key
            $.confirmOn.deleteOverlay($element);
            $.confirmOn.deleteBox($element);
            $(document).off('keydown.confirmon.close');
        }
    });
}

confirmOn.convertArguments = function(options, events, selector, data, handler) {
    if (typeof options === 'object') {
        $.each(options, function(key, val) {
            if (typeof val === 'string') { //Options provided so shift all args to left
                confirmOn.providedOptions = options;

                options = events;
                events = selector;
                selector = data;
                data = handler;
                return false;
            } else { //No options
                confirmOn.providedOptions = {};
            }
        });
    } else {
       confirmOn.providedOptions = {}; 
    }

    if (selector == null && data == null && handler == null) {
        //(events[S], handler)
        selector = events;
        events = options;
    } else if (data == null && handler == null) {
        //(events[S], selector, handler)
        //(events[S], data, handler)
        data = selector;
        selector = events;
        events = options;
    } else {
        handler = data;
        data = selector;
        selector = events;
        events = options;
    }

    if (typeof events === 'object') {
        //Implementation .on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )
        return {
            events: events,
            selector: selector,
            data: data
        };
    } else {
        //Implementation .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
        return {
            events: events,
            selector: selector,
            data: data,
            handler: handler
        };
    }


};

$.confirmOn.attachHandlers = function($element, handler, event) {
    var classPrepend = $element.data('confirmon').options.classPrepend;
    $('.' + classPrepend + '-box button').eq(0).on('click', function(){
        $.confirmOn.deleteOverlay($element);
        $.confirmOn.deleteBox($element);
        handler.call($element.get(), event, true); //Call the handler function. the TRUE parameter indicates that the user pressed the YES button

    });

    $('.' + classPrepend + '-box button').eq(1).on('click', function(){
        $.confirmOn.deleteOverlay($element);
        $.confirmOn.deleteBox($element);
        handler.call($element.get(), event, false); //Call the handler function. the FALSE parameter indicates that the user pressed the YES button

    });

 };

 $.fn.confirmOn = function(options, events, selector, data, handler) {
    var userHandler;
    if (typeof events === 'function') {
        userHandler = events;
        events = confirmHandler;
    } else if (typeof selector === 'function') {
        userHandler = selector;
        selector = confirmHandler;
    } else if (typeof data === 'function') {
        userHandler = data;
        data = confirmHandler;
    } else if (typeof handler === 'function') {
        userHandler = handler;
        handler = confirmHandler;
    }

    var $element = $(this);
    var onArgs = $.confirmOn.convertArguments(options, events, selector, data, handler);
    $.confirmOn.setOptions($element, $.confirmOn.providedOptions);

    $element.on(onArgs.events, onArgs.selector, onArgs.data, onArgs.handler);

    function confirmHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();            
        $.confirmOn.createOverlay($element);
        $.confirmOn.showOverlay($element);
        $.confirmOn.createBox($element);
        $.confirmOn.showBoxAndFocusNo($element);
        $.confirmOn.handleEscKey($element);
        $.confirmOn.attachHandlers($element, userHandler, event);            
    };

};

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: down voter, please comment!!

Comment: Assuming `confirmOn` is a valid library you are using, you would have to prevent the default action _before_ you would do anything else with it. Just a note - I was not the downvoter.

Comment: what is `confirmOn ` ?

Comment: Your code make no sense at all. The remove funntion removes a set of elements from the dom. The scope "this" is the button in this case. If you like to do something with the href value use attr("href") instead. If you like to see a alert use alert("text");

Comment: instead of pasting the plugin source code, please just put the link to the plugin side, copy whole source code is a mess to us

Comment: sure, the link to the plugin is https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm):

**Try this:**

```
$("#demo").click(function() {
    var confirm1 = confirm('Dialogue');
    if (confirm1) {
      $(this).remove();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {
    $('#demo').confirmOn('click', function (e, confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) { // Clicked yes
            document.location.href= $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).remove();
            $('#msg_button_1').remove();
        } else { // Clicked no
            $('#msg_button_1').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EN8pf/3)**

Comment: Thank you very much imbondbaby. but this will not work for me as Windows.location can be any link in the site. i am trying to trigger multiple events on different pages but with the same header.

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for. You Rock!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
<script>
    $(function() {
         $('.log_button').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed) {
             if(confirmed){
                //$('#demo').remove();
                $('#demo').click();
             }else{
                alert("not go");
             }
         });
    });
</script>
```

is this the thing that you actually want to do? click the button and then go to the link?

Comment: Se0ng11, i would like to actually go to the link when click OK in the Alert popup